# How to store a twitter API response in react and use on later in components

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api, twitter

I need help in saving a response from Twitter API and then use it later on in parent component, eventually pass it down as props to children components in a React project. I am using a package called twitter that uses acquired credentials for the call.

```
var Twitter = require('twitter');

var client = new Twitter({
    consumerKey: "",
    consumerSecret: "",
    bearer_token: '',
    port: ""
});

client.get('statuses/user_timeline', function(error, tweets, response) {
    if(error) throw error;
    console.log(tweets);  // The favorites.
    console.log(response);  // Raw response object.
});
```

Comment: Just keep in mind if you store your key and secret in React, even if the code is monitored, it can be extracted using dev tools or similar. It is not secure stored on the client.

Comment: Thanks a lot!What would be the best way to use it in local development and what would you suggest, on how to make this API call?

Comment: Regardless of the credentials management, have you considered React’a Context API Or Redux?

Comment: I will check out thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in the front, nothing is private. The best way is to have your back end, i think with node and save that in the process env variables.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like i did:

server side code:

Main component:

```
const express = require('express');
const server = express();
const path = require('path');   
const tweets = require ('./tweets')
const distFolder = path.join(__dirname, '../my-app/build')

server.use("/api/tweets", tweets, function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  next();
}
)

server.use(express.static(distFolder))

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 9090)
```

tweets.js component:

```
    router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  client.get('statuses/user_timeline', params, function(error, tweets, response) {    
    if (!error) {     
      res.send(tweets);          
    } 
    else {
      res.status(500).json({ error: error });
    }}
  )})
```

Now i can make a GET to /api/post and express will be redirected to client.get and return tweets.

> See my React Component:

```
lass Notifications extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      hits: [],
      isLoading: false,
      error: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });

    Axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:9090/api/tweets'
    ,{
     headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',          
     }}
    )   
    .then(result => this.setState({
        hits: result.data,
        isLoading: false
    }))
    .catch(e => console.log(e));
  }
    render() {    
const { hits, isLoading } = this.state;    
if (isLoading) {
  return (
    <div className='feed_main'>       
          <h2 className="js-ariaTitle">
            Loading...
          </h2>
        </div>
  )
}
else {
  return hits.map((data) =>    
    <div className='feed_main'>
      <strong className="fullname">{data.user.name}</strong>
      <article
        key={data.id}
      >{data.text}
      </article>
      <br />          
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
}    

export default Notifications;
```